# How to get users that was created on specific day of week on ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to create some kpi's on ruby on rails.

How can i count all users that was created on sunday or on wednesday for example?

I now that ruby can get day of week with the follow code for example:

```
u = User.last
u.created_at.wday #==> wday get the day of week (0: sunday, 1: monday..)
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
User.where(created_at.wday: 0).count
```

And I don't want to loop each user, check if it was created on sunday and put it in an array, because it seems to be costly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MYSQL you can use [dayofweek](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp)

```
User.where('DAYOFWEEK(created_at) = ?', 0).count
```

For Postgres this should do the trick:

```
User.where("extract(dow from created_at) = ?", 0)
```

EDIT: For SQLITE the following works:

```
User.where("strftime('%w', created_at) = ?", 0)
```